# CSS Animations for a scrolling list

Tags: angularjs, css-animations, animate.css

I have created a simple scrolling list component in Angular.js, borrowing quite a bit from the [`uib-bootstrap` carousel component](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/carousel/carousel.js). It uses the `ng-show` directive with `ngAnimate`, the `ng-hide-add`, `ng-hide-remove`, `ng-hide-add-active` and `ng-hide-remove-active` classes, and [Animate.css](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css).

[Here's a plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/S0RxmyHHPuJT1yGwp7YJ?p=preview)

As you can see, I am struggling on getting the CSS styles just right so that it appears like a smooth transition between items; the items jerk around a bit when toggling between `position: absolute` and `position: relative`.

I have tried fiddling with the elements' paddings and margins, to no avail.

I think the answer lies in the CSS, rather than the Angular code, but any pointers to make this look good much appreciated:

```
[list-scroller] {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

[list-scroller] li {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

scroller-item {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

scroller-item.ng-hide-add {
    animation: fadeOutUp 0.5s;
    display: inline-block !important;
}
scroller-item.ng-hide-add-active {
    position: absolute !important;
}

scroller-item.ng-hide-remove {
    animation: fadeInUp 0.5s;
    display: inline-block !important;
}
scroller-item.ng-hide-remove-active {
    position: absolute !important;
}
```

I'm also not sure why on the plunker there is a delay between the exiting element hiding and the entering element showing.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution:

```
.ng-hide-add.ng-hide-add-active {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```